# Display array of an object in HTML table using PHP and send it as an email

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I want to send emails to my users and data are in array of an object, so I want to display data in an HTML table and send it as an email. I don't know what I've done wrong.

This is the sample of the data

```
[
  {"created":"2020-02-05","cat":"Transport","amount":7000,"comment":"The accommodation "},
  {"created":"2020-02-05","cat":"Accomodation","amount":9000,"comment":"goimg ibadan"}
]
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$html = "<html>
   <body> <h1> Mr. $data->names  Claim expense on  $data->created </h1>
    With below information <br>";
$html .="
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> Date </td><td> Category </td><td> Amount </td> <td> Description </td>
        </tr> $claim";

foreach($claim  as $row ){
  $html .="<tr>
      <td>{$row->created }</td><td>{$row->cat}</td><td>{$row[amount]}</td><td>{$row[comment]}</td>
     </tr>";
}

$html .=  "<tr>
      <td> Advance : $data->advance </td><td> Total Amount : $data->total </td><td> GrandTotal : $data->granTotal </td> <td>  </td>
    </tr>
  </table>";
$html .="<p>you can login to approve or disapprove this request</p>
  </body></html>";
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. What actually happens when you run this code? Do you get an error, or some unexpected output? Please give more details.

Comment: Also, your data looks like a JSON string. So you can't use it directly in PHP like that. have you first turned it into an object using json_decode() before trying to work with it? Again it's unclear - there's no obvious connection between the sample data and the `$data`  object in the code.

Comment: I can also see some potential syntax errors e.g. `$row[amount]` and `$row[comment]` should probably be `$row["amount"]` and `$row["comment"]`, or even `$row->amount` and `$row->comment` (depending on the structure of the $data variable).

Comment: So please tell us specifically what issue you are facing, then we can narrow down the problem and give you better advice.

Comment: Below is the Origin JSON data from front end 
{"claim":[{"created":"2020","cat":"Accomod","amount":1000,"comment":"th "},{"created":"02-08","cat":"Trans","amount":10,"comment":"Transport ."},{"created":"12345","cat":"Others","amount":3000,"comment":"Daily"}],"total":8000,"grandtotal":7000,"advance":"1000","userId":"18"}

Comment: I want to display this data in user-readable, either in HTML Table and send it to the user via email,
@ADyson, and others I will be so grateful for any help
Thank you all

Comment: Ok. That's what you want. As I mentioned, we need to understand what **problem** is happening in your code. You gave us some code. Please tell us the problem with it. (We can't just give you some different code, because we don't know exactly how you want it to look. We also don't know anything about your email setup, for the second part of the requirement.)

Comment: Thank for the support @ADyson, It was unable to display on the screen

Comment: That's still too vague for anyone to help. Do you understand how to debug your application? You need to narrow down the problem and give a clearer, specific, more detailed description of the behaviour.

Comment: Thank so  much for the support, I really appreciate your effort, I just want to display JSON data in HTML Table. Thank

Answer (score 0):

After surfing net and research, I later realized, I have to do something in common, the code below solved the problem.

````
```$tbclaim= "<table class='table table-bordered table-responsive table-info' style='border: #4f1915 thick'>
                  <tr>
                  <td> Date </td><td> Category </td><td> Amount </td> <td> Description </td>
                  </tr>";
                  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data["claim"]); $i++){
                    $tbclaim .= "<tr style='background-color: green; color: #ffffff;'  >";
                    $tbclaim .= "<td>" . $data["claim"][$i]["created"] . "</td>";
                    $tbclaim .= "<td>" . $data["claim"][$i]["cat"] . "</td>";
                    $tbclaim .= "<td>" . $data["claim"][$i]["amount"] . "</td>";
                    $tbclaim .= "<td>" . $data["claim"][$i]["comment"] . "</td>";
                    $tbclaim .= "</tr>";
                  }
                   $tbclaim .= "</table>";```**strong text**
````